# LINQ to check boolean value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List AffiliateConfigurations

```
public class AffiliateConfiguration
{
    public int AffiliateConfigurationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

with following Sample Data:

```
(1,"AddOn",true)
(2,"DummyEmail",false)
(3,"ProviderType",true)
```

Basically I want to perform some action, if my List contains any item whose name is equal to ProviderType and its IsActive value contains false.
I tried this, is this the right approach?

```
if (AffiliateConfigurations.Any(x => x.Name.Equals("ProviderType")) && !AffiliateConfigurations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("ProviderType")).IsActive)
 {
    //perform some action
 }
```

Comment: Your code will take the very first item whose name is `RoviderType` and evaluate its `IsActive`-property - even when it is `true`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as this condition below? You don't have to check twice since you can directly access `IsActive` property.

```
if (AffiliateConfigurations.Any(x => x.Name.Equals("ProviderType") && !x.IsActive))
{

}
```

Comment: This is clear. Just curious, mine will work fine too right? just that its not the right approach

Comment: @HumaAli No, because if there are two records with *name = ProviderType* and the *first IsActive value is true* then it will not satisfy the condition.

Comment: Perfect! Its clear now. But in my case ProviderType exists just once. Anyway, it cleared my concept

Answer (score 3):

You can directly check `IsActive`

```
if (AffiliateConfigurations.Any(x => x.Name.Equals("ProviderType") && !x.IsActive ) )
 {
    //perform some action
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing two validations:
- First you check if there is at least one item in your collection that the name matches "ProvidersType".
- The you iterate through your collection again in order to find such item (it will exist since the first verification has passed) and check if it is active.

You can do that in a *single run*:
    if (AffiliateConfigurations.Any(x => x.Name == "ProviderType" && x.IsActive == false /* or "!x.IsActive" */))
    {
    //perform some action
    }

If your "AffiliateConfigurations" is an IEnumerable most of the linq method that can "filter" your collection will accept a `Func<TypeBeingFiltered, bool>` or a `Predicate<TypeBeingFiltered>` (like `Any`, `Where`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, ...), you can give any type of code bock as part of those parameters as long as you return a `bool` value at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this condition like #John Woo said

```
x => x.Name.Equals("ProviderType") && !x.IsActive
```

which loop through the AffiliateConfigurations for only one time, where in your approach it have to loop through for two time one for Any part and one for FirstOrDefault part...